# Растушевка в css. Обводка контуров изображения

Tags: изображения, css

Есть картинки на странице. 
При наведении мышью, хочу сделать выделение с растушевкой.

Но, как сделать эту растушевку?
2. Как сделать, чтобы border был не прямоугольный, а обтекал сам рисунок?

Comment: Непрямоугольные выделения можно сделать с помощью map area. Чтобы выделать, задавать границы и т.д. нужно использовать дополнительные инструменты, например, http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Comment: Координаты прописывать вручную для каждого изображения? Нельзя ли автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Есть онлайн-помощнки, но в них всё равно руками приходится тыкать нужные точки. В моей задаче картинки были мелкими и они не подошли. Я использовал adobe dreamweaver, в которой выделение по координатам реализовано намного удобнее, хотя никогда в жизни её (AD) не использую.